# On convergence of WOT

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ Hilbert space. $\{A_n\}_{n\ge0}$ a sequence in $B(H)$ such that the sequence
$\{\langle A_nx,y\rangle\}_{n\ge0}$ converges for all $x,y\in H$.

Can we show that there exist $A\in B(H)$ such that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\langle A_nx,y\rangle=\langle Ax,y\rangle$$
for all $x,y\in H$.

I guessed one can use [Uniform Bounded Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) but couldn't figure out a concrete argument.

This question is motivated from the fact (can be proved using Uniform Boundedness Principle)-
If $\{A_n\}_{n\ge0}$ a sequence in $B(H)$ such that the sequence
$\{ A_nx\}_{n\ge0}$ converges for all $x\in H$ then there exist $A\in B(H)$ such that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}A_nx= Ax$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\sigma:H\times H\to\mathbb{C}$ by setting
$$\sigma(x,y):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle A_nx,y\rangle $$

This is a well defined map and one can easily see that this is linear in the first argument and conjugate linear in the second argument. Moreover, note that
$\{\|A_n\|\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset[0,\infty)$ is a bounded sequence: You can find a proof of this result (using the principle of uniform boundedness) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628832/wot-convergence-implies-norm-boundedness).

So now there exists $M>0$ such that $|\sigma(x,y)|\leq M\cdot\|x\|\cdot\|y\|$ for all $x,y\in H$. This proves that there exists a bounded operator $A\in B(H)$ so that $\sigma(x,y)=\langle Ax,y\rangle$, as you can deduce from [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997897/correspondence-between-bounded-sesquilinear-forms-and-bounded-linear-operators).